# regaining missing rows and column names in pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to manipulate my file (in which every row has a name ,as rows name not a separate column, and columns also have name) and perform downstream analysis. during this process I have to convert the values to log value using `numpy` and then again I have to convert `numpy` array to pandas `dataframe`. but during this process I will loose both column name and rows name.
here is what I did:

```
df = pd.read_table(infile, index_col=0)
df2 = np.log2(np.array(df))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

to add column name to the pandas `dataframe` I used the following code:

```
colname = list(df.columns)
df3.columns = colname
```

but I did not manage to add the rows name to the new `dataframe`. do you know how to do that?

here is input data (df):

```
    ABC20190124 ABC20190156
CCNO    61.300048   1.865438
MYC 7949.585246 2229.654372
CD79A   0.954767    1223.411451
```

here is the output I am getting (df3):

```
    0   1
0   5.9378  0.8995
1   12.9566 11.1226
2   -0.0667 10.2566
```

and here is the expected output:

```
    ABC20190124 ABC20190156
CCNO5.9378  0.8995
MYC 12.9566 11.1226
CD79A   -0.0667 10.2566
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here convert to numpy array is not necessary, only work with `df`:

```
df = pd.read_table(infile, index_col=0)
df3 = np.log2(df)
```

Your solution should be changed with `index` and `columns` parameters in `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.read_table(infile, index_col=0)
df2 = np.log2(np.array(df))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4], 'B':[7,8,9]})
df3 = np.log2(df)
print (df3)
          A         B
0  2.000000  2.807355
1  2.321928  3.000000
2  2.000000  3.169925
```